# Helm merge and dict directives?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I one of Helm chart examples I come across the following lines:

```
{{- define "common.deployment" -}}
{{- $common := dict "Values" .Values.common -}} 
{{- $noCommon := omit .Values "common" -}} 
{{- $overrides := dict "Values" $noCommon -}} 
{{- $noValues := omit . "Values" -}} 
{{- with merge $noValues $overrides $common -}}
```

But I can't find in helm docs information about omit, merge and dict directives.

Comment: Can you provide the chart source?

Comment: https://github.com/CodeJjang/helm-microservices-example/blob/master/common/templates/_deployment.yaml

Comment: Since this question was originally written, the Helm documentation added a [Template Function List](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) that includes all of the Sprig extensions, including those mentioned here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These template functions are actually from an underlying package [sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig) that [helm uses](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/go.mod#L8).

- ## [dict](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/dicts.md#dict)

---

Creating dictionaries is done by calling the `dict` function and passing it a list of pairs.

The following creates a dictionary with three items:

```
$myDict := dict "name1" "value1" "name2" "value2" "name3" "value 3"
```

- ## [merge / mustMerge](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/dicts.md#merge-mustmerge)

---

Merge two or more dictionaries into one, giving precedence to the dest dictionary:

```
$newdict := merge $dest $source1 $source2
```

This is a deep merge operation but not a deep copy operation. Nested objects that are merged are the same instance on both dicts. If you want a deep copy along with the merge than use the `deepCopy` function along with merging. For example,

```
deepCopy $source | merge $dest
```

`mustMerge` will return an error in case of an unsuccessful merge.

- ## [omit](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/dicts.md#omit)

---

The `omit` function is similar to [pick](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/dicts.md#pick), except it returns a new `dict` with all the keys that do not match the given keys.

```
$new := omit $myDict "name1" "name3"
```

Answer (score 4):

They're part of a template library called [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/), and more specifically its functions for working with [dictionaries](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html).

Using constructs like this it's possible to run templates with what looks like alternate values objects, constructing them from other parts of the original values.  In your example, say the next line (inside the `{{ with }}...{{ end }}`) block was just `{{ toYaml .Values }}`.  If the original `values.yaml` file contains something like

```
common:
  a: "one"
  b: "two"
a: "three"
c: "four"
```

the code you show will in effect "promote" the common content to the top level, but making actual top-level values override it, and you will get out

```
a: "three"
b: "two"
c: "four"
```

(`$common` is a dictionary containing the contents of `.Values.common`, under a top-level `"Values"` key.  `$noCommon` is a dictionary containing all of `.Values` except the `common` key, still under `"Values"`, and `$noValues` is a dictionary containing `"Chart"`, `"Release"`, and the other top-level values.  These all get merged together into a single dictionary with `$noCommon` overriding `$common`.)